# suppose a program is running on 5 threads.If an extra thread is added,what factors should be considered?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, hardware, process-management

Add up question:
Will the efficiency of the system increases if i add an extra thread?if yes/no,why?

This question is asked in qualcomm interview. It is related to thread management topic in Operating system

I tried to search on the internet, but i didnt find a detailed answer. I have less knowledge on threads and thread management system in operating system.

Comment: I'm not even sure that the question makes sense.  And "the efficiency of the system" is too imprecise for an accurate answer.  Are you sure that you copied the question accurately?

Comment: This is an open question, not one with a simple yes/no answer (like often in interviews). For example, It depends what threads are doing, whether SMT is enabled on the hardware or not, the exact kind of hardware, etc. Based on that the answer can be either clearly yes, or clearly no. Details are missing to give a simple answer.

Comment: Re, "running on 5 threads," That's kind of an upside-down way of thinking about it. Really, it's the _threads_ that run the code.